# How do I insert integer values in a MySQL query without having to wrap them in single quotes?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm taking lessons at lynda.com on 'PHP with MySQL Essential Training'.
Everything has gone great so far but I got to a point where I needed to do something a little different in order to achieve the same results as the instructor in the videos.
Here's his code:

```
<?php
 $query = "INSERT INTO subjects (
             menu_name, position, visible
          ) VALUES (
             '{$menu_name}', {$position}, {$visible}
          )";
?>
```

When he executes this everything works fine, but in order to get it to work for me I need to also wrap the $position, and $visible variable in single quotes so it looks like this:

```
<?php
 $query = "INSERT INTO subjects (
             menu_name, position, visible
          ) VALUES (
             '{$menu_name}', '{$position}', '{$visible}'
          )";
?>
```

It's the only way that I can get the code to work otherwise I get an error that says:
"You have an error in your SQL syntax, check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use..."
I understand wrapping $menu_name in single quotes since it represents a string, but the other two represent integer values.  Why won't my code execute without the quotes?  Is there something I need to change in a config file?  Is it considered a better practice to use the the quotes  on integers and let SQL do the conversion for me, or should I not need to use those quotes?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  If you can't tell by now, I'm kind of a noob.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You shouldn't have to wrap the integer values in quotes. Can you post what you get when you `echo $query`?

Comment: What are the types of those columns in your table?

Comment: You should use prepared statements, that way you won't have to worry about wrapping or not wrapping in quotes. Example [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: position is int and visible is tiny int

Answer (score 0):

Check the values of your integers. If your variables don't have any value, then you end up with a query like

```
INSERT INTO subjects (
         menu_name, position, visible
      ) VALUES (
         'menu name', , ,)
```

If your values are correct integer values, than your query should work.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Fixed!

Well, I said I was a noob, and a noob error was exactly what did me in.

I was missing an '=' in a piece of code and that was causing me to get those MySQL syntax errors.
Here's the code I fixed:

```
<p>Visible:
   <input type="radio" name="visible" value="0" /> No
    &nbsp;
   <input type="radio" name="visible" value="1" /> Yes
</p>
```

Originally, when I was getting the syntax errors, I failed to put an equals sign between value and "1"

It was a silly mistake, but it still always feels good when you figure out a mistake that was causing you headaches.  I still learned a lot in the process.  Thanks for all your help!